# How to highlight a range in highstock?

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

Is there a way to do the red highlight in a highstock/highchart graph as shown in the picture below? i.e. display the part below $4000 as a red zone and fill it with red color ?

Thanks

[image: Chart Mockup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. In the current version of Highcharts and Highstock you can add a [`plotBand`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands). This can have a shading to it and cover any starting point you wish. In version [3.0](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released) (currently beta) of Hightcharts there is a way to allow for [colored threshold shading](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/YWVHx/) of the lines. Now, if you only need to support SVG browsers (not IE 6, 7, or 8) you can do this [hack](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PMyHQ/) mentioned [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/787281-threshold-option-for-colors).

Myself, I would use the plotBands for now and wait for stable 3.x release.